# IBM i Access ODBC driver returning only first letter of column names

Tags: db2, iseries, db2-midrange

I'm new to DB2 and am connecting to a DB2 for i (V7R1) database using unixODBC and the IBM i Access ODBC driver for Linux.

When I query the database, the results only include the first letter of the column names. For example, a typical query run with the `isql` utility will give me something that looks like this:

```
SQL> SELECT column1, column2 FROM schema.table WHERE column1 = 12345
+--------+---------------------------------+
| C      | C                               |
+--------+---------------------------------+
| 12345  | Lorem ipsum dolar sit           |
+--------+---------------------------------+
SQLRowCount returns -1
1 rows fetched
```

This is a problem for me because when I try to query the database in applications (e.g. using the `pyodbc` library for Python), I can't access the results by column name; both columns are named "C" in the result set.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is it possible to change this behavior? (How?)

EDIT:

This happens even if I try to give the columns aliases:

```
SQL> SELECT column1 as foo, column2 as bar FROM schema.table WHERE column1 = 12345
+--------+---------------------------------+
| F      | B                               |
+--------+---------------------------------+
| 12345  | Lorem ipsum dolar sit           |
+--------+---------------------------------+
SQLRowCount returns -1
1 rows fetched
```

Comment: Odd. What happens if you try and alias them using `column1 as blahblah`?

Comment: It gives me the first letter of the alias, strangely enough. Though that was a good thought -- I'll add it to the question details.

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/issues/25

Comment: Thanks! pyodbc does get the column names correctly if I use it with Python 2.7. So that solves my immediate problem. I'm curious about what's going on with the `isql` tool, though -- that's just a command-line utility.

Comment: Which version of i5/OS are you on? that may be affecting things, as DB2 for i is actually integrated with the OS and only upgraded as the OS is upgraded.

Comment: I'm using DB2 for i V7R1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The defect with only the first character of the column name being returned is described in IBM APAR SE63700:
http://www-912.ibm.com/n_dir/nas4apar.NSF/b6c9b771e38b5ea2862564c00079d110/0f43bb0435716de586257f340041ed7a?OpenDocument

The fix should be integrated into the new version of the IBM Access Client Solutions Application Package for Linux, due mid-July 2016.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a bug with the specific version of IBM's driver I was using. I was using the ODBC driver from IBM i Access Client Solutions Linux AP v07.03.00.

I replaced that driver with the ODBC driver from IBM i Access for Linux v7.1.0-1.0 and now everything works as expected.